# How to use Context with Views' Contextual Filters

Tags: views, 8

I have content type `City`. I have a view page with contextual filters to show the cities at the URL pattern `locations/<city id>`. I want to use Context to add blocks to these cities pages but I dont seem to be able to figure out how to get it done.

In D7 I used the [Context Request Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_request_path) to be able to do this. In D8, I dont see how this is possible.

The `Request Path` condition only checks internal URLs which *I think* is useless for me since there is no pattern that can isolate the city pages. The `Node Bundle` doesnt work because the page is technically a View and not a Node.

How can I use Context to place blocks on a view page that uses contextual filters?

Comment: Is there are reason to can't use the block's visibility settings to display only in `/locations/*`? Are these context specific blocks?

Comment: Yes. They are context specific. `location/<city_id>` The `city_id` in the URL indicates which city is being viewed.

Comment: Adding a block visibility setting for the Request path "/locations/*" should suffice.
If you limit the views context argument to the City node type (see validation in the contextual filter) /locations/* will only apply for City nodes.
What's the content of the block? If it's related to the city as well you could create a views block with a contextual filter.